# Extension does not work in all theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, extensions

My problem that many times when I install an extension, it works in a theme but not in others.
For example this extension : [SharingTool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/addthis-sharingtool-6043.html)s
It works in default theme but not in the theme I use.
What is the problem for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all the extensions phtml files in either your active theme directory or in the `app/design/frontend/base/default` directory. This also applies for the `skin` files of the extension

Comment: Thanks that's work :) and i understand also what is the problem

Comment: You're welcome, did this answer your whole question?